# How can I rescale data by a learnable constant in a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm working on a class of machine learning problems which fit functions from scalars to vectors. Let's suppose the output of this function is just a set of two-component vectors. I have found that my neural network is doing a good job of fitting this function, except that the outputs are consistently off by a  multiplicative factor. To fix this, I would like to insert a layer into my neural network which rescales the outputs by a learnable multiplicative factor.

Essentially, such an operation would look like `LinearLayer[]` without biases and with the constraint that every weight is identical. Is there a built-in layer for this? Other seemingly related functions like `NormalizationLayer[]` seem much more involved than the desired operation of rescaling the final output by a learnable factor.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something like a ConstantTimesLayer, but with only one parameter that is applied to all values in the input.

Since Mathematica 12.2, ConstantTimesLayer[] translates to a specific NetGraph object. We construct a similar NetGraph:

```
scaleLayer[opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 NetGraph[{NetArrayLayer["Output" -> {}], 
   ThreadingLayer[Times, 1]}, {{1, NetPort["Input"]} -> 2}, opt]
```

Which then you can use in your neural network.

For example:

```
net = NetChain[{
   5, Tanh, 5, Tanh, 5, scaleLayer[]}]
```